# Error When iterate over with a DataView component that is dynamically visible

Tags: html, merge, wicket, textfield, dataview

doubt the wicket ... I'm using a DataView and is being released the following error:

```
"... Expected close tag is' <td wicket: id =" lblRowspan "> 'Possible attempt to embed component (s)' <input type =" text "placeholder =" Item "wicket: id =" txtNomeBem "class = "form-control" /> 'in the body of this component Which discards its body ... "
```

The situation is as follows in this DataView am using ROWSPAN to merge some cells, 100% works well if there is no type of component in the lines that I'm mixing, for example, if the lines that I'm using rowSpan write a sentence works. .. but when I insert the TextField component in the cell does not.

In the application I'm developing need to show a TextField so that the person enter some information, only it's always thrown the exception that pointed up.

here is my code:
(html)

```
<tr wicket:id="dataGruposSelecionados">
    <td wicket:id="lblRowspan">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Item" wicket:id="txtNomeBem"
               class="form-control" />
    </td>
<tr/>
```

Here is my java

```
dataViewGruposSelecionados = new DataView<ItemBemDto>("dataGruposSelecionados", new Provider(listaDeGrupos)) {

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(Item<ItemBemDto> item) {    

    Label lblRowspan = new Label("lblRowspan",item.getModelObject().getNomeItemGrupo());
.
.
.
    int tamanho = listaBens.size();
    if(primeiroLoop)
    {                    
        lblRowspan.add(new AttributeAppender("rowspan", new Model<Integer>(tamanho), " "));
         primeiroLoop = false;
     }else{
         lblRowspan.setVisible(false);
     }
.
.
.
.
    item.add(lblRowspan);
    item.add(newTextFieldNomeItem(item));
  }
}
```

as I said, it works 100% if in place of the TextField I leave it blank or type something in HTML, the merge works ... but when I insert any component within the 'td' is thrown the exception ...

Comment: I might be wrong; but your code indicates lblRowSpan is parent and text field txtNomeBem is child. Is that how you have text field added into your method newTextFieldNomeItem(item)? Just curious.

Comment: It's like I said, the first column of this DataView will be merged depending on a rule that for this example I discarded it is working, let's assume that I have 4 lines in Dataview and make a merge with it, these four lines will include a Textfield. .. as I said the merge works perfectly, the exception is thrown when I try to include a textField this cell that did merge ...
.
LblRowspan is the Father is the label that will receive the instruction of 'rospan' (and it worked) ...

Comment: .
The 'txtNomeBem' is the 'newTextFieldNomeItem (item)', is the component that must be shown in the column that made the merge is a simple textfield, follows the code textfield below:
.
.
.

private TextField <String> newTextFieldNomeItem (Item <ItemBemDto> item) {
         TextField <String> field = new TextField <String> ("txtNomeBem" new PropertyModel <String> (item.getModelObject (), "nomeItemGrupo"));
         field.add (StringValidator.maximumLength (200));
         return field;
     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer :)
.
Instead of a label to control the 'rowspan' the Dataview I created a WebMarkupContainer receiving ROWSPAN ... well, below the HTML and java solution I found.

```
<td wicket:id="containerRowspan">
    <div wicket:id="panelNomeGrupo">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Item" wicket:id="txtNomeBem" class="form-    control" />
    </div>
</td>
```

Code Java:

```
     WebMarkupContainer containerRowspan = new WebMarkupContainer("containerRowspan");

     int tamanho = listaComTodosBens.size();

     if(primeiroLoop || !item.getModelObject().getNomeItemGrupo().equalsIgnoreCase(nomeAnterior)){
           containerRowspan.add(new AttributeAppender("rowspan", new Model<Integer>(tamanho), " "));
          primeiroLoop = false;
        }else{
           containerRowspan.setVisible(false);
        }

     PanelNomeItem panel=new PanelNomeItem("panelNomeGrupo", item);
     panel.setVisible(mostrarPainel);
     containerRowspan.add(panel);
     item.add(containerRowspan);
```

Answer (score 0):

`<tr/>` should be `</tr>`